# NullReferenceException even though setting value while returning JSON

Tags: c#, .net

In the results Im getting `null` value, getting `NullReferenceException` when the return is happening. I have used nullcheck yet I'm getting the error

```
results = //Here one get call is happening and the value is null
 return Json(new
 {
   HasPermission = hasPermission,
   EmployeeCount = results == null? 0 : results.Count,
 });
```

Comment: what is your payload? can you show us from addwatch? what is the value or example value?

Comment: have you tried `EmployeeCount = results?.Count ?? 0` ? And what line number does the Exception point to?

Comment: The line numbers for exceptions are not seldom off by one (or even a few) lines while the compiler moves things around in the symbol file. Make sure to check the immediate vicinity of this code as well for potential `null` accesses.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Track.WebSite
  StackTrace:
   Line number exactly points to the place where return statement starts

Comment: @Fildor tried that, didn't work still got null exception

Comment: You need to show more code . And full call stack. Split the statement to: `var a = new json.. ; result = a;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has problem in **Json()**
what is this method do? Could you check it??
*The below code is compiled successfully in VSCode

[image: The below code is compiled successfully in VSCode]

I even tried using **System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize** still not error.

[image]

Comment: I'm returning JSON, the scenario you posted is a bit different

Comment: Yes, you returning JSON ,but the code proof that the statement in parentheses is not error so  what could be wrong if not Json ?

Comment: I'm getting null exception, not an error